# Why is php code not giving the output of image?

Tags: php, image, php-gd

this is the code

```
<?php
  $x = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 250);
  $y = imagecolorallocate($x, 120 ,156,100);
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($x);
?>
```

It is giving output as 
  The image "http://localhost/firstprogram.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I also tried Example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php and it still displayed the same message.

And also can someone tell if header is necessary or not and what exactly is it used for?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but you define $y without using it, should something be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

you made a image, you allocate it, but you did not draw it.
try this code

```
<?php
 $x = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 250);
 $y = imagecolorallocate($x, 120 ,156,100);
 imagerectangle($x, 50, 50, 150, 150, $y);// draw the rectange of image
 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 imagejpeg($x);
?>
```